# Ionic: Understanding navigation and routing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am learning navigation and routing in Ionic from http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-1/

& I would like to understand the mapping, I didn't get it clearly from docs.

below code is from my app.js

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      console.log('In Config');
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')

       $stateProvider.state('home', {
           url: '/home',
           views: {
               home: {
                   templateUrl: 'home.html'
               }
           }
         })
       })
```

& below code is from Index.html

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive">
    <ion-tab icon="ion-home" ui-sref="home">
      <ion-nav-view name="home"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
```

What I understood is that ui-serif is mapped with states name. I am not getting how url,templateUrl & ion-nav view name are related to or mapped to each other because if I change any one of these my app doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me change a bit your exemple so you can understand a bit more:

```
 $stateProvider.state('homeState', {
           url: '/homeUri',
           views: {
               homeName: {
                   templateUrl: 'home.html'
               }
           }
         })
```

Is referenced in your page like that :

```
  <ion-tab icon="ion-home">
      <ion-nav-view name="homeName"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
```

Or your can access  to it with a a href :

```
<a href="{{homeUri}}">
```

or usign ui-router routing

```
<a ui-sref="homeState">
```